# How to create multiple buttons dynamically based on their text contents In android?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I want to calculate the width of dynamically create multiple buttons based on their text contents to fit them in the layout without using any third party library.for example:-
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyUuK.png

Comment: So, you want to get the total width X, that the parent layout should have in order to fit all the buttons?

Comment: @azizbekian ,yes..if buttons doesn't fit the row of layout then that button should get down to the second row of layout and so on.

Comment: Highly simplified solution would be to implement a custom view, measure all childViews, ask them to layout base on constrain you have set for them. OR use a third party library that does exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/greenfrvr/hashtag-view)

Fully customizable widget that help alot.

Answer (score 0):

The layout you are talking about is `FlowLayout`. [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) (one of Android Framework engineers) answers to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474533/1083957).

[Here](http://pastebin.com/xAT6bKAM) you can see a simple implementation of `FlowLayout` given by Romain.

Also, you can have a look at source code of [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) that has much more advanced implementation of that functionality and is maintained by google.